# option to select always falls into the first value, inexplicable

Tags: php, html, optional-parameters

```
echo "<td>Language</td>";
echo "<td><select id='language' name='language'>
            <option value=''>Select...</option>
            <option value='en_US'>English(US)</option>
            <option value='en_AU'>English(AU)</option>
            <option value='en_US'>English(UK)</option>
          </select>
      </td>";
```

I have that code snip enclosed in a form to post of a php file and when i choose to submit the form, I can see those options. However, after i click a button to save what I have selected, the language above is always set to the first option (en_US) no matter what ever.

Comment: Well, it's a 50% chance... You have `en_US` twice in four options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to check your last submitted value to determine which option should receive the `selected` attribute. You're currently not doing this, so the browser sets the first option as the selected one.

```
// Define all languages
$l = array('en_US'=>'English(US)','en_AU'=>'English(AU)','en_UK'=>'English(UK)');

// Prepare an options variable
$o = "";

// Construct our options list
foreach ( $l as $k => $v )
  $o .= sprintf("<option value='%s'%s>%s</option>", 
          $k, $k === $_POST["language"] ? " selected" : "", $v);

// Echo our Select menu
echo "<select id='language' name='language'>$o</select>";
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/PkwNYHbO

Answer (score 0):

```
$selected = $_POST["language"];

echo "<td><select id='language' name='language'>
            <option value='' ".($selected==""?"selected":"").">Select...</option>
            <option value='en_US' ".($selected=="en_US"?"selected":"").">English(US)</option>
            <option value='en_AU' ".($selected=="en_AU"?"selected":"").">English(AU)</option>
            <option value='en_US' ".($selected=="en_US"?"selected":"").">English(UK)</option>
          </select>
      </td>";
```

I usually do something like this. The first part gets the value of the language sent to server then checks each option for same value, then put "selected" to that element with the same value.

In case, `($selected=="en_US"?"selected":"")` means, if currently selected language is "en_US", "selected" will be concatenated to the tag as it's attribute, thus giving the output:

```
<option value='en_US' selected>English(US)</option>
```

Or you could do Jonathan's solution, it's more elegant.